# mySQL Transaction not working

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

I have the following code:

```
<?php

// Conexion a MySQL



$mysql_link = mysql_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '010101' );

if  (!$mysql_link) {
    die('No se pudo conectar a la DB: ' . mysql_error());

}

$mysql_db = mysql_select_db('test', $mysql_link);

if (!$mysql_db) {
die ('No se pudo seleccionar DB: ' . mysql_error());
    }

$mysql_doc_query = "INSERT INTO documents (name, wfid, docid, archivo) VALUES     ('{$CodDoc}: {$documentoNombre} de {$DNI}', '{$workflowNombre}', '{$documentoNombre}',     '{$archivoNombre}' );
      INSERT INTO keywords (document_id, keyword, value) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),     'DNI', '{$DNI}' ), (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Cuit Empleador',
      '{$cuitEmpleador}' ), (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'DigitalizadoPor', '{$usuario}' ),
  (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Direccion IP', '{$IP}' ), (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Ubicacion',     CONCAT('pdfs/',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'.pdf') );";

   // Insert en mysql
 $log = fopen('/dev/shm/log.txt', 'w');
  if( $log ) {
      fwrite( $log, $mysql_doc_query );
  }

  mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");
  if (mysql_query($mysql_doc_query) == TRUE)
  {
      mysql_query("COMMIT");
  echo "\nCOMMIT!";
  }
    else {
      mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
      echo "\nROLLBACK!";
  }
  mysql_close($mysql_link);
fclose ($log);
?>
```

It's always giving me ROLLBACK but I don't understand why.

Any clue on this? The code generated in the log.txt archive can be executed in PHP MY ADMIN without problems. (I know the variables aren't referenced but this is part of a larger script).

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Debug with `mysql_error()` in your ROLLBACK block before you do the rollback

Comment: Transactions can only be used on InnoDB tables.

Comment: what's that `keywords` query doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysql_query()` only supports *one statement* at a time.  You are executing multiple `INSERT` statements in one go:

```
$mysql_doc_query = "INSERT INTO documents (name, wfid, docid, archivo) VALUES     ('{$CodDoc}: {$documentoNombre} de {$DNI}', '{$workflowNombre}', '{$documentoNombre}',     '{$archivoNombre}' );
      // Oops, new statement here! mysql_query() can't do that.
      INSERT INTO keywords (document_id, keyword, value) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(),     'DNI', '{$DNI}' ), (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Cuit Empleador',
      '{$cuitEmpleador}' ), (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'DigitalizadoPor', '{$usuario}' ),
  (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Direccion IP', '{$IP}' ), (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'Ubicacion',     CONCAT('pdfs/',LAST_INSERT_ID(),'.pdf') );";
```

This could be debugged with `mysql_error()` inside your `ROLLBACK` block:

```
  if (mysql_query($mysql_doc_query) == TRUE)
  {
      mysql_query("COMMIT");
  echo "\nCOMMIT!";
  }
  else {
    echo "Error in query: " . mysql_error();
    mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
    echo "\nROLLBACK!";
  }
```

If you need to do two `INSERT`s, you will need two separate calls to `mysql_query()`, and check for errors after each one.  On failure of either, do your `ROLLBACK`.

Comment: Ok but I thought that using transactions would work :S, should I use PDO?

Comment: @Jorge PDO doesn't support multiple statements in one call either. However switching to PDO is recommended simply because it is a better API supporting prepared statements and because the old `mysql_*()` API is facing deprecation

Comment: @Jorge MySQLi has [`mysqli_multi_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) and also supports prepared statements.

Answer (score 1):

Your testing method is bad. mysql_query() returns a boolean FALSE on error, or a result hand on success. By PHP's type conversion rules, a result handle tests equal to true. You must use the strict boolean comparison, and excplicitly test against false:

```
if (mysql_query($mysql_doc_query) !== FALSE)
```

Comment: My first thought too, but it is an INSERT statement and will return boolean TRUE on success.

Comment: Manual says:  For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.  

Thats why I used it. Originally I used        if (mysql_query(query)) {} instead of == TRUE

Comment: True enough. but you are also trying to do **TWO** inserts in a single query call. The mysql driver does not allow this as an anti-sql injection mitigation method. So you're getting back boolean false, and since you're not checking mysql_error() to get the REAL reason for failure, you're just getting the useless "failed" message.

Comment: Ok but I thought that using transactions would work :S, should I use PDO?

Comment: No. transactions have nothing to do with this limit. it's built into the php/mysql drivers. And yes, you should switch to PDO, or at least mysqli. mysql_*() is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't send two mysql queries at the same time. You're sending two different INSERT queries.

Also you must send your queries without ';' since it's added automatically.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to run transactions consists in the following steps:

```
 mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0"); //by default this is 1
 mysql_query("START TRANSACTION"); // start the transaction

 //run all the queries, possibly in a loop
 $q1 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO  .... ");
 $q2 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO  .... ");

 //check the success of all the queries and based on that commit or rollback
 if ($q1 and $q2) {
     mysql_query("COMMIT");
 } else {        
     mysql_query("ROLLBACK");
 }
```